# Removing repeating letters from a given word

Tags: c, string

I am practicing strings, for the first time, and I am trying to remove consecutive repetitive letters from given words and print it. 
Say the word is committee, the out put will be comite.

My logic was to compare consecutive letters in the given word and store the letters into another string if they are not same.

When I compile and run my code I get weird symbols. 
What is the mistake in my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char word[20],modword[20];
    int i=0,j=0;
    gets(word);
    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if (word[i]!=word[i++])
        {
        modword[j]=word[i];
        j++;
        }

    }
    puts(modword);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: They say you shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: Don't use gets because is deprecated. Use fgets instead.

Comment: @Michi it isn't deprecated. As of C11, it is completely *gone*, no longer supported by the standard in *any* fashion.

Comment: C strings are *null-terminating*, google it up. You are also using `i++`, do you really want to? Perhaps you want to use `i+1` instead.

Comment: @WhozCraig YOU right about the standard, but as long as the function is still present in some libraries (until it will be gone) there is still use of it. This is why **deprecated** is still OK here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply certain changes, e.g.

```
char word[20] = {0};
char modword[20] = {0};
int i = 0, j = 0;

fgets(name, sizeof(word), stdin);

for (i=0; i < sizeof(word) - 1;i++)
{
    if (word[i] != word[i+1])
    {
        modword[j] = word[i];
        j++;
    }

}
```

Comment: it worked. 
Can you tell me when to use gets and fgets?

Comment: @stick Use `gets()` in no situation.

Comment: You should explain about those changes rather then showing a piece of code.

Comment: I understand you, but you do know that SO is not a tutorial site and your Answer looks like one. That was my Point.

Comment: @Michi I understand your comment, but like I said most of it has been covered already :)

Comment: Based on the OPs decision (he accepted your Answer) make your Answer to be a Tutorial. The OP needed a Tutorial and he got one.

Comment: @Michi Although note some aspects of my answer I deliberately left unexplained such that with little of thought the OP had to understand himself what the problem was in the code.

Answer (score 3):

- `word[i]!=word[i++]` invokes *undefined behavior*. It is intuitively explained as because whether of `word[i]` and `word[i++]` will be evaluated first is not specified and the evaluation order will change which element will be accessed.
- Avoid using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 20

int main(void)
{
    char word[MAX_LENGTH + 1],modword[MAX_LENGTH], *lf;
    int i=0,j=0;
    fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
    if ((lf = strchr(word, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
    for (i=0;i<MAX_LENGTH;i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || word[i-1]!=word[i])
        {
            modword[j]=word[i];
            if (word[i] == '\0') break;
            j++;
        }

    }
    puts(modword);
    return 0;
}
```

Points:

- Avoid using `gets()` to avoid buffer overrun.
- Using magic numbers is not a good idea.
- No increment of `i` in the loop. `word[i-1]` won't be evaluated when `i == 0` thanks to short-circuit evaluation.
- Stop the loop when terminating null-character is reached.

Comment: Good answer, though for completeness, you should also point out that they need to null terminate the new string, which the original code didn't do.